How to make bar widths the same and category widths variable?
I have a bar chart with multiple datasets which include empty values. I use skipNull to hide the empty values. Currently each group (month) has the same width, and the width of the bars is inversely proportional to the number of bars in a group. I'd like all bars in the chart to have the same width, and the groups to have variable widths.
This is my current code:


const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [3, null, null],
      skipNull: true,
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: [1, 2, null],
      skipNull: true,
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      data: [4, 1, 3],
      skipNull: true,
    },
  ],
};

new Chart(
  document.querySelector('#chart'),
  {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
  }
)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="100" id="chart"></canvas>



This is more or less how I'd like the chart to look (excuse my poor Photoshop skills):

I tried barPercentage and barThickness, but they don't affect the group width.

Use maxBarThickness property:


const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [3, null, null],
      skipNull: true,
      maxBarThickness: 50,
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: [1, 2, null],
      skipNull: true,
      maxBarThickness: 50,
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      data: [4, 1, 3],
      skipNull: true,
      maxBarThickness: 50,
    },
  ],
};

new Chart(
  document.querySelector('#chart'),
  {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
  }
)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
<canvas width="500" height="100" id="chart"></canvas>




The category widths are still the same.

Update. Although the OP was probably no longer interested in their question, I managed to
improve the code all by myself, so I'm posting it here, with the hope that someone will find it
useful. From the previous version a bug related to animation was corrected, the scope was extended
(e.g., now the x axis grid lines are drawn at the borders of categories; interaction.mode "dataset"
is supported for tooltips; x axis label default management works (label rotation of removal)) and the
setup was cleaned up by putting all the code in a plugin, which leaves user data and options unchanged.
Here it is, with OP's data:


const pluginFlexCat = {
    _computeFlexBarCoordinates(categoryWidths, start = 0){
        // computes the coordinates of the labels of the bar to achieve categoryWidths spacing of categories
        this.$xBarPositions = categoryWidths.reduce(
            (ax, wi, i) => {
                let next = 0;
                if(i === categoryWidths.length - 1){
                    next = ax[i] + categoryWidths[i];
                }
                else{
                    next = ax[i] + 2 * categoryWidths[i + 1];
                    if(next < ax[i]){
                        next = ax[i] - 2 * categoryWidths[i + 1];
                    }
                }
                return [...ax, next];
            },
            [start + categoryWidths[0] / 2, start + 3 * categoryWidths[0] / 2]);

        this.$xLabelPositions = categoryWidths.reduce(
            (ax, wi, i) => [...ax, ax[i] + (wi + categoryWidths[i + 1]) / 2],
            [start + categoryWidths[0] / 2]
        );
        this.$xLabelPositions.pop();
        this.$xAxisMax = start + categoryWidths.reduce((s, w) => s + w);
    },
    beforeInit(chart){
        const categoryWidths = data.datasets.reduce(
            // count non-null items for each category
            (bw, {data}) => Array.from(
                {length: Math.max(bw.length, data.length)},
                (_, j) => (bw[j] ?? 0) + (data[j] === null ? 0 : 1)
            ),
            []
        );

        if(categoryWidths.includes(0)){
            throw new Error('Invalid data, zero-length category found', {cause: 'categoryWidth'});
        }

        this._computeFlexBarCoordinates(categoryWidths);

        this.$originalLabels = data.labels;
        data.labels = this.$xBarPositions;
        data.datasets.forEach(
            dataset => {
                dataset.data.push(null);
                dataset.barThickness = "flex";
            }
        )

        chart.options.scales.x.offset = false;
        chart.options.scales.x.type = "linear";
        //chart.options.scales.x.grid.display = false;
        chart.options.scales.x.min = 0;
        chart.options.scales.x.max = this.$xAxisMax;

        const plugin = this;
        chart.options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks.title = function(tooltipItems){
            if(tooltipItems.length > 0){
                tooltipItems.forEach(item => {item.label = plugin.$originalLabels[item.dataIndex] || "";});
                const item = tooltipItems[0];
                const labels = plugin.$originalLabels;
                const labelCount = labels ? labels.length : 0;
                if(this && this.options && this.options.mode === 'dataset'){
                    return item.dataset.label || '';
                }
                else if(item.label){
                    return item.label;
                }
                else if(labelCount > 0 && item.dataIndex < labelCount){
                    return labels[item.dataIndex];
                }
            }
            return '';
        };
        chart.options.plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label = function(tooltipItem){
            return (tooltipItem.raw !== null) ? undefined : null;
            // undefined means "use original label"; null means "no label"
        }
    },
    _setBarElementXPx(bar, x){
        bar.x = x;
        if(bar.$animations?.x){
            bar.$animations.x._from = x;
            bar.$animations.x._to = x;
        }
    },
    beforeUpdate(chart){
        const plugin = this;
        chart.scales.x.afterTickToLabelConversion = function(){
            this.ticks = Array.from({length: plugin.$xLabelPositions.length}, (_, i) => ({
                value: plugin.$xLabelPositions[i], label: plugin.$originalLabels[i] || ''
            }));
        }
    },
    afterUpdate(chart, {mode}){
        const xAxis = chart.scales.x;
        if(!this.$gridLineComputerModified){
            this.$gridLineComputerModified = true;
            this.$original_computeGridLineItems = xAxis._computeGridLineItems.bind(xAxis);
        }

        if(!chart.$catMoveX){
            // get the space to the left and right of each category, average those spaces;
            // compute the displacement for each category in real units, such that the spaces get even
            const catLeft = [], catRight = [];
            for(let iDataset = 0; iDataset < data.datasets.length; iDataset++){
                const _parsed = chart.getDatasetMeta(iDataset)._parsed;
                const bars = chart.getDatasetMeta(iDataset).data.map((bar, i) => _parsed[i].y === null ? null : bar);
                bars.pop();
                const barPercentages = bars.map(bar => bar && (chart.options.barPercentage ??
                    bar.$context?.dataset?.barPercentage));
                const left = bars.map((bar, i) => bar && xAxis.getValueForPixel(bar.x - bar.width / barPercentages[i] / 2)),
                    right = bars.map((bar, i) => bar && xAxis.getValueForPixel(bar.x + bar.width / barPercentages[i] / 2));
                left.forEach((l, i) => {
                    if(l !== null){
                        catLeft[i] = Math.min(l, catLeft[i] ?? l)
                    }
                });
                right.forEach((r, i) => {
                    if(r !== null){
                        catRight[i] = Math.max(r, catRight[i] ?? r)
                    }
                });
            }
            const catSpaces = catLeft.flatMap((min, i) => i === 0 ? [min] :
                [(min - catRight[i - 1]) / 2, (min - catRight[i - 1]) / 2])
                .concat([xAxis.max - catRight[catRight.length - 1]]);
            const avg = catSpaces.reduce((s, x) => s + x) / catSpaces.length;
            const deltaUniformSpaces = catSpaces.map(sp => avg - sp);
            chart.$catMoveX = catLeft.map((_, i) => deltaUniformSpaces.slice(0, 2 * i + 1).reduce((s, x) => s + x));
        }

        if(!chart.$catMoved || mode === 'resize'){
            chart.$catMoved = true;
            const catLeft = [], catRight = [];
            for(let iDataset = 0; iDataset < data.datasets.length; iDataset++){
                const {_parsed, data: bars} = chart.getDatasetMeta(iDataset);
                bars.pop();
                bars.forEach((bar, category) => {
                    if(_parsed[category].y !== null){
                        const newX = xAxis.getValueForPixel(bar.x) + chart.$catMoveX[category];
                        catLeft[category] = Math.min(catLeft[category] ?? newX, newX);
                        catRight[category] = Math.max(catRight[category] ?? newX, newX);
                        this._setBarElementXPx(bar, xAxis.getPixelForValue(newX));
                    }
                });
            }
            const newTickValues = catLeft.map((left, i) => (left + catRight[i]) / 2);
            xAxis.ticks.forEach((tick, i) => {tick.value = newTickValues[i]});

            const nCat = chart.$catMoveX.length;

            const plugin = this;
            xAxis._computeGridLineItems = function(chartArea){
                const items = plugin.$original_computeGridLineItems(chartArea);
                if(!items || items.length === 0){
                    return items;
                }
                if(items.length > nCat - 1){
                    items.splice(nCat - 1);
                }
                items.forEach(
                    ((item, i) => {
                        item.tx1 = xAxis.getPixelForValue((catRight[i] + catLeft[i + 1]) / 2);
                        item.tx2 = xAxis.getPixelForValue((catRight[i] + catLeft[i + 1]) / 2);
                        item.x1 = xAxis.getPixelForValue((catRight[i] + catLeft[i + 1]) / 2);
                        item.x2 = xAxis.getPixelForValue((catRight[i] + catLeft[i + 1]) / 2);
                    })
                )
                return items;
            }
        }
    }
};

const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [3, null, null],
            skipNull: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            //data: [1, 2, null],
            data: [1, null, 2],
            skipNull: true
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 3',
            data: [4, 6, 5],
            skipNull: true,
        },
    ],
};

new Chart(
    document.querySelector('#chart'),
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            //barPercentage: 1,
            //categoryPercentage: 1,
            //animation: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    border: {dash: [4, 4]},
                    grid: {
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)',
                        tickLength: 1
                    }
                }
            },
            interaction: {
                //mode: "dataset"
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            pluginFlexCat
        ]
    }
);
<div style="height:300px; width:500px">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>



This fiddle contains the same plugin with a random data generator that
was used to test the plugin.

Bar charts with variable category or bar widths can be obtained in chart.js using
barThicknes: "flex",
however, it is not simple to set the widths according to predefined numeric data.
I gave a simple example of such an application in a comment,
but that post was abandoned and I haven't had the chance to refine the code.
This question poses a supplemental challenge - obviously, the category width has to be proportional to
the number of non-null data points in that category; however, the width of each bar is modified
by categoryPercent option; this will create a different spacing of a three-bar category from a one-bar category
and results in visually defective charts.
The only solution I found was to recenter the bars and the axis labels with a plugin, in the afterUpdate
callback.
This is a rather lengthy piece of code, and explaining it in detail makes little sense. The central part
is changing the x axis to a linear type and positioning the categories to exact values computed by
"reverse engineering" the function computeFlexCategoryTraits
of chart.js source. This also involves adding an invisible category by pushing a null to each of the
datasets data; that is because the number of parameters required to position n categories
with computeFlexCategoryTraits is n+1.
Here's a snippet using this contraption for the original example data:


const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [3, null,  null],
            skipNull: true,
            barThickness: 'flex',
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            data: [1, 2, null],
            //data: [1, null,  2],
            skipNull: true,
            barThickness: 'flex',
        },
        {
            label: 'Dataset 3',
            data: [4, 6, 5],
            skipNull: true,
            barThickness: 'flex',
        },
    ],
};

function flexBarCoordinates(categoryWidths, start = 0){
    // computes the coordinates of the labels of the bar 
    // to achieve categoryWidths spacing of categories
    const x = categoryWidths.reduce(
        (ax, wi, i)=> {
            let next = 0;
            if(i === categoryWidths.length - 1){
                next = ax[i] + categoryWidths[i];
            }
            else{
                next = ax[i] + 2 * categoryWidths[i + 1];
                if(next < ax[i]){
                    next = ax[i] - 2 * categoryWidths[i + 1];
                }
            }
            return [...ax, next];
        },
        [start + categoryWidths[0]/2, start + 3*categoryWidths[0]/2]);

    const xBarCenters = categoryWidths.reduce(
        (ax, wi, i)=>[...ax, ax[i]+(wi+categoryWidths[i+1])/2],
        [start + categoryWidths[0]/2]
    );
    xBarCenters.pop();
    const end = start + categoryWidths.reduce((s, w)=>s+w);
    return {xBarPositions: x, xLabelPositions: xBarCenters, xAxisMax: end};
}

const barWidths = data.datasets.reduce(
    // count non-null items for each category
    (bw, {data}) => Array.from(
        {length: Math.max(bw.length, data.length)},
        (_, j) => (bw[j]??0) + (data[j] === null ? 0 : 1)
    ),
    []
);
// barWidths is [3, 2, 1] for this data

const {xBarPositions, xLabelPositions, xAxisMax} = flexBarCoordinates(barWidths);

data.labels1 = data.labels;
data.labels = xBarPositions;
data.datasets.forEach(
    dataset => dataset.data.push(null) // add an invisible category
)


new Chart(
    document.querySelector('#chart'),
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options:{
            //barPercentage: 1,
            //categoryPercentage: 1,
            animation: false,
            scales:{
                x:{
                    type: 'linear',
                    min: 0,
                    max: xAxisMax,
                    afterBuildTicks(scale){
                        scale.ticks = Array.from({length: xLabelPositions.length}, (_, i)=>({
                            value: xLabelPositions[i], label: ''+xLabelPositions[i], label1: scale.chart.data.labels1[i]
                        }));
                    },
                    afterTickToLabelConversion(scale){
                        scale.ticks = scale.ticks.map(({value, label1}) => ({value, label: label1}))
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        //includeBounds: false,
                        //stepSize: 0.1,
                        //minRotation: 90
                    },
                    grid:{
                        display: false
                        //color: 'red'
                    },
                    offset: false,
                }
            },

            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        title([ctx]){
                            return ctx.chart.data.labels1[ctx.dataIndex];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins:[
            {
                afterUpdate(chart, {mode}){
                    const xAxis = chart.scales.x;
                    if(!chart.$catMoveX){
                        // get the space to the left and right of each category, average those spaces; 
                        // compute the displacement for each category in real units, such that the spaces get even 
                        const catLeft = [], catRight = [];
                        for(let iDataset = 0; iDataset < data.datasets.length; iDataset++){
                            const _parsed = chart.getDatasetMeta(iDataset)._parsed;
                            const bars = chart.getDatasetMeta(iDataset).data.map((bar, i) => _parsed[i].y === null ? null : bar);
                            bars.pop();
                            const barPercentages = bars.map(bar => bar && (chart.options.barPercentage ??
                                bar.$context?.dataset?.barPercentage));
                            const left = bars.map((bar, i) => bar && xAxis.getValueForPixel(bar.x - bar.width / barPercentages[i] / 2)),
                                right = bars.map((bar, i) => bar && xAxis.getValueForPixel(bar.x + bar.width / barPercentages[i] / 2));
                            left.forEach((l, i) => {if(l!==null){catLeft[i] = Math.min(l, catLeft[i] ?? l)}});
                            right.forEach((r, i) => {if(r!==null){catRight[i] = Math.max(r, catRight[i] ?? r)}});
                        }
                        const catSpaces = catLeft.flatMap((min, i) => i === 0 ? [min] :
                            [(min - catRight[i - 1]) / 2, (min - catRight[i - 1]) / 2])
                            .concat([xAxis.max - catRight[catRight.length - 1]]);
                        const avg = catSpaces.reduce((s, x) => s + x) / catSpaces.length;
                        const deltaUniformSpaces = catSpaces.map(sp => avg - sp);
                        chart.$catMoveX = catLeft.map((_, i) => deltaUniformSpaces.slice(0, 2 * i + 1).reduce((s, x) => s + x));
                    }

                    if(!chart.$catMoved || mode === 'resize'){
                        chart.$catMoved = true;
                        const catLeft = [], catRight = [];
                        for(let iDataset = 0; iDataset < data.datasets.length; iDataset++){
                            const {_parsed, data: bars} = chart.getDatasetMeta(iDataset);
                            bars.pop();
                            bars.forEach((bar, category) => {
                                if(_parsed[category].y !== null){
                                    const newX = xAxis.getValueForPixel(bar.x) + chart.$catMoveX[category];
                                    catLeft[category] = Math.min(catLeft[category] ?? newX, newX);
                                    catRight[category] = Math.max(catRight[category] ?? newX, newX);
                                    bar.x = xAxis.getPixelForValue(newX);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        const newTickValues = catLeft.map((left, i)=>(left + catRight[i])/2);
                           xAxis.ticks.forEach((tick, i) => {tick.value = newTickValues[i]});
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
<div style="height:300px">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>



